# Binary regressor - what happens if people move from one category to the other?

Tags: regression, binary-data

Suppose I have the following regression model:

Monthly alcohol consumed A as independent variable, regressed on a binary regressor S (S = 1 if smoker, S = 1 if non-smoker), and through OLS I get an estimate for the coefficient of S, say 2 pints. So 2 pints is the difference in average monthly alcohol consumed between smokers and non smokers.

Imagine now the government introduces anti-smoking campaign, and proportion of smokers fall by 10% points.

Does that affect the monthly alcohol consumed?

My initial thought was no: a smoker will on average still drink 2 pints more than a non-smoker, it doesn't matter whether there are more non-smokers around or not.

But then I thought that surely the OLS estimate will be different, if I run a new regression? Since the smokers who turned into non-smokers will arguably (at least in the short term) carry over their increased propensity to drink, and thereby reducing the difference in average alcohol consumption between the two groups.

I think I have now answered my own question: No, a reduction in proportion of smokers does not affect monthly alcohol consumption. It has nothing to do with the value of the binary regressor.

Can someone please confirm/improve this reasoning?

Apologies for any confusions.

Comment: This reasoning confuses an analysis of *association* with an analysis of *causation.*  Logically, you cannot deduce anything about the effects of an anti-smoking campaign on the amount of alcohol consumed (per capita or total) from your model alone.  Using common sense you can see that any change in the OLS fit after the campaign is unpredictable and could have multiple causes, even if nobody changes their drinking habits, simply because you don't know the drinking habits of those who stopped smoking (nor of those who started smoking, of which there will be some!).

Comment: Apologies I should have been more aware of that and clearer in my language. I'm not looking at a causal relationship, but trying to predict purely, so the question is just what the associated change is. That too is 0 I presume?

Comment: This isn't a statistical question insofar as a simple cross-sectional, or even pre-post design does not provide an identifiable effect. Current smokers who quit smoking may drink more, or smokers who retain smoking after the intervention. The closest we can come to a prediction of the post-hoc event is to closely model the smoking and drinking process. It makes sense the time series might be positively correlated through cyclic and/or lagged effects. In that case you would predict less drinking following a glut of smoking cessation.